# Why my media only screen on react not working / changing my css react

Tags: css

I have a chunk of code and I want to change it for mobile view with the media only screen. But the problem for some part of the code the media only screen didn' work (the css didn't change) but for some other part it work.

My Code:

```
<div id='community' className='encotekiCommunity text-center'>
    <Col>
        <h1 className='mb-5 FontGothamRoundedBold'>Join Our Community</h1>

        <Row className='my-5' style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Col>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <a href='https://www.instagram.com/encoteki/' target='_blank'>
                        <div class="circle" style={{margin:'0px 35px'}}>
                            <img src="./Images/ig_logo.png" alt="Image" class="image" />
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        <h2 style={{marginTop: '150px'}}>And Save The World</h2>
    </Col>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/// It work
.encotekiCommunity h1{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/// It work 
    .circle {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;  /* make the container circular */
        overflow: hidden;  /* hide any content that overflows the container */
        background-color: white;
        padding: 15px;
    }


@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
     /// It didn't Work 
    .encotekiCommunity h1{
        font-size: 20px;
    }

   /// It also work
    .circle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

}
```

Comment: If one of the rules inside the media query is working, then it's probably not the media query itself. Try inspecting the element with your browser dev tools, there's a good chance another selector is overriding your `font-size: 20px;`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `///` to comment in CSS files, it is not the best method, it is better to use `/*...*/` , but that should not be the problem, anyhow I tested this and it works fine for me just like this, I mean I removed comments and used `class` instead of `className`, but you are using tailwind or something like that, and maybe problem lies somewhere else, something may be overriding your selector, so, could you please provide more code for us?
try and run this code and resize it and see.

```css
.encotekiCommunity h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* make the container circular */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* hide any content that overflows the container */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .encotekiCommunity h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='community' class='encotekiCommunity text-center'>
  <h1 className='mb-5 FontGothamRoundedBold'>Join Our Community</h1>
  <div>
    <a href='https://www.instagram.com/encoteki/' target='_blank'>
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="./Images/ig_logo.png" alt="Image" class="image" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <h2>And Save The World</h2>
</div>
```